# I need to introduce a 2 seconds delay when user click on save button in angular

Tags: c#, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular2-directives

I have the following code, when user clicks on save button, it should do nothing but just changes the text of that button to saved and then make it disabled. I achieved this with two buttons and the controller code as follows.

The issue with this is, it does displays the save button also just for a second when I click on save while loading the saved button and then the save button disappears (Just flickers), I don't want that to happen. What's wrong? Also, how can I introduce 2 seconds delay then show "Save' button.

```
    <button type="button" id="saveEnabled"  ng-click="ctrl.onClick()" ng-if="ctrl.Status !== 'Clicked'">Save</button>
    <button type="button" id="saveDisabled" disabled="disabled" ng-if="ctrl.Status === 'Clicked'">Saved</button>


ctrl.onClick = function() {
      ctrl.Status = 'Clicked';
  };
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you're into Angular, use it's native [$timeout](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) function.

```
ctrl.onClick = function() {
 $timeout(
   function(){
      ctrl.Status = 'Clicked';
   }, 2000);
};
```

**Note**: you have to inject $timeout as a dependecy, but `setTimeout()` would also suffice

Comment: Bark, sorry that didn't work, but this worked ctrl.onClick = function() { $window.setTimeout(function() {
          $scope.$apply(function() {
              ctrl.Status = 'Clicked';
          });
      }, 3000);}

Comment: However, I still have that problem of that idiotic save button being flickered :( How to stop that flickering upoon clicking on Save Button. I mean, the Save Button also appears once you click on Save and then it disappears in fraction of second. I don't want that bad experience to user

Comment: I suggest looking into Angular's [ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate). Although you could accomplish that by adding a class that has `transition`

Comment: NO Barak, that is not the impact here, but its two consequtive ng-ifs. I am trying to do it with ng-switch, how to do, do you know? Same code above in ng-switch construct

Answer (score 0):

You can Use `setTimeout()`

`var delay=2000; //2 second`

`setTimeout(function() {`
`//your code to be executed after 2 second`
`}, delay);`